# converge inequality for squares of primes

Tags: prime-numbers, inequalities, prime-number-theorem

Does this inequality always hold :
$$\frac{1}{6} \pi ^2 \prod _{i=1}^x
   \frac{\left(p_i\right){}^2-1}{\left(p_i\right){}^2}\leq \frac{1}{p_x}+1 $$

such that $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime number

Comment: Two suggestions. First, you should add the number-theory tag to questions of this sort. Second, you seem to be asking a lot of questions of a similar nature in a short amount of time. You got a complete answer to one of your questions, and it seems to me that the methods used there would similarly be useful for this question. So until you spend a week or two working on it yourself, you probably shouldn't jump right in and ask it on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. We have
$$
\frac{1}{6} \pi ^2 \prod _{i=1}^x
   \frac{\left(p_i\right){}^2-1}{\left(p_i\right){}^2}=\prod_{i>x} \frac{p_i^2}{p_i^2-1}\leqslant \prod_{n=p_x+1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n^2-1}=\frac1{p_x}+1.
$$